# callback not executing in JEST testing?

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, use-effect

callback inside useEffect not executing in JEST testing?Do I have to wait or something else.
Repeat-callback inside useEffect not executing in JEST testing?Do I have to wait or something else.
Repeat-callback inside useEffect not executing in JEST testing?Do I have to wait or something else.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the names of your function calls, yes, you would have to wait. `fetch` implies that you are performing an ansynchronous (a promise) call for data. That would, most likely, set some form of state. Doing that would rerender something (which takes a moment). Waiting for data changes is one of the hardest bits to wrap your head around when writing testing.

Comment: I am new in JEST testing.So can you please tell me how I can wrap the test for wait?

Comment: it("check for TrendsPageContainer", async () => {
  const props = {
   history: {},
   location: {},
   activeLang: "hi",
   activeLangEn: "Hindi",
   match: {
    params: {}
   }
  };
  const component = await renderer.create(
   <Provider store={store}>
    <Router>
     <TrendsPageContainer {...props} />
    </Router>
   </Provider>
  );

  const tree = component.toJSON();
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
 });

Comment: this is not working

Comment: Are you using React-Testing-Library with Jest? If not, you should. They have a number of utility methods to help you with this.

Comment: Yes I am using React-Testing-Library

Comment: `await waitFor(() => /*assertion*/)` will automatically wait 1 second for an `expect` to return true

Comment: `it("check for TrendsPageContainer", async () => {
  const props = {
    history: {},
    location: {},
    activeLang: "hi",
    activeLangEn: "Hindi",
    match: { params: {} },
  };
  const component = renderer.create(
    <Provider store={store}>
      {" "}
      <Router>
        {" "}
        <TrendsPageContainer {...props} />{" "}
      </Router>{" "}
    </Provider>
  );
  const tree = component.toJSON();
  await waitFor(() => {
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
`

Comment: still not covered

Comment: You might need to lookup some tutorials on writing tests with RTL. You `render(Component)`, then query the DOM for that changes you are testing, using one of their many queries.